# How to get the unique values of nested lists in jekyll data

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I want to use jekylls `data` to store a list of links to sites, where different tags can be applied to the single items:

```yaml
# _data/links.yml
- title: css tricks
  url: https://css-tricks.com
  tags:
    - tag: css
    - tag: grid
- title: css tricks2
  url: https://css-tricks.com2
  tags:
    - tag: css
    - tag: flex
```

Now I want to produce a list of tags, and a list of links, grouped by tag.

For posts, `posts.tags` would generate this list, for `data` this doesnt seem to work.

I tried to use `{{ site.data.links | group_by_exp 'tags', 'tags.tag' }}` and other `group_by` statements like

```
{% assign grouped_res = site.data.links | group_by: 'tags' %}
{{ grouped_res }}
```

But this will group by the unique full array (in pseudo-notation: `[{tag: css}, {tag: grid}]`).

While the grouping is added sugar, I would already be happy just to join and unique the available tags, for starters.

How can I get a list of tags in that example?

I've seen this being asked for simple attributes, but not lists.

Answer (score 1):

So I found out how to generate the list of tags:

```
{% for link in site.data.links %}
  {% assign tags = tags | concat link.tags %}
{% endfor %}

{% assign all_tags = tags | uniq | map: "tag" | sort %}
```

However, now when I want to generate a list where links are listed grouped by tags, the only solution I see is to **iterate over the list of tags** (`all_tags`) **and within that iterate over all `link`s** and check whether the current tag is included in the list of tags. I would assume there is a more clever and more performant way to do that (sure enough, performance in a static site generator is not the most important thing to optimize for, but still ...).

```
{% for tag in all_tags %}
### {{tag}}
  {% for link in site.data.links %}
    {% assign link_tag_names = link.tags | map :'tag' %}
    {% if link_tag_names contains tag %}
      {{ link.title }} ({{ tag }})
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```